# SO Reputation score up and down

Tags: support, reputation

Hi,

This morning when I logged in my rep was 2,758

As far as I can see I have had one up vote and and an accepted answer today.  My rep then went down to 2,743.  How did this happen?

Note: Rep is not 2,843 as I linked my account to Meta.

Thanks

Barry

Comment: You mean, you got 100 points and then lose 15 points? probably, check http://stackoverflow.com/reputation for more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that 2758 is the reputation after the upvote and accepted answer. In other words, that your reputation when you left last night was 2733. Subsequently, after identifying that information, you saw your reputation drop by 15 points to 2743.

Because the drop is 15 points, the most likely scenario is that an acceptance vote on one of your answers was retracted. You won't notice this on your envelope activity report unless that specific acceptance that just happened was the one revoked. The nature of this action is that it subtracts by removing the original gain, not by adding a negative gain, so this is reflected in both a [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and your envelope activity report by removing the original vote.

There's also the possibility that a combination of question and answer upvotes equalling 15 (1q1a or 3q) were retracted in the same manner.

Naturally, though, if you check your reputation audit, and you see some negatives around that time, that would be the cause. But if you find that neither the reputation audit or your envelope activity report show any recent loss that would result in this, yet a *visible* loss of points occured, then it will have been caused most likely by the retraction of votes.

Comment: I've checked the reputation tab in my account and there is a total of two down votes which were actioned recently (total of -4).  I can't see any other negatives.  If someone retracts an upvote or an accepted answer is it shown on the reputation tab?

Comment: @Barry It is not shown as a loss. It is shown as the removal of the original gain. So unless you've memorized which ones of your answers are accepted and every vote, it won't be easy to find it.