# My rep decreased, not due to a downvote

Tags: support, reputation, questions, voting

I had 5518 re, but when I refreshed the page, it suddenly dropped to 5508. How?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is probably because someone who previously up voted one of your answers subsequently removed the up vote.

EDIT:

This is also true for Accepted answers. If your answer is marked as accepted you will receive +15.  However, if the OP changes their mind and marks a different answer as accepted then your Rep score will decrease by 15.

There isn't really any way to know which questions/answers these events occur on - unless you memorise all of your answers and upvotes.

See this comment from [Grace Note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note)

> It is not shown as a loss. It is shown
>   as the removal of the original gain.
>   So unless you've memorized which ones
>   of your answers are accepted and every
>   vote, it won't be easy to find it.

from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54721/so-reputation-score-up-and-down/54723#54723) I posted a while ago

Comment: wouldn;t it be a downvote?

Comment: @org.life.java: No. After someone votes up *or* down, they can remove that vote within a time window. So it'll be as though they never voted. In other words, if someone upvotes your answer then someone else downvotes your answer you get 10 - 2 = 8 net reputation. Someone voting up or down then removing that upvote gives nor take any net reputation.

Comment: <typo-correction> Someone voting up or down then removing that vote gives nor take any net reputation. </typo-correction>

Comment: @Insilico, it's not _exactly_ "as though they never voted." The system still remembers that a vote was cast at one point, and won't let the users re-change the vote on that post unless/until it's edited.</nitpick>

Comment: A bit of an update from my earlier stuff; on your own you can't confirm whether a specific post has had votes withdrawn, but you *can* confirm whether a specific answer has been unaccepted. If you check out the timeline view of a question, it will show unacceptance like [in this case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/47676/timeline "Demo by popular demand"). Of course, it doesn't make it easier to *find*, simply it just lets you confirm if or when you *do* find it.

Comment: @Popular Demand: Right, which is why I didn't say "exactly as though they never voted." :-) The result is similar though, save for the extra detail you mentioned.

Comment: @Insilico, okay. Your comment was good, but there have been posts on MSO complaining about that behavior, so I wanted to point it out.