# Upvote is not being counted

Tags: support, questions, voting

I has been upvoted but my rep didn't increased by 10 as it should.

for [abstract method of a set length array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922848/abstract-method-of-a-set-length-array-in-java)

I haven't reached daily cap yet.

Question hasn't been closed.

**It happens for each and every and every answer i provide**

[image]

also cleared cached also tried from different machine its shoving me +1 vote

Comment: Additionally, the vote decomposition shows 0 up, 1 down. Looks odd

Comment: @Jose K - do'h. Ignore me.

Comment: This question looks very strange. It shows a total of 1 up vote but in the breakdown it shows 0 up votes and 1 down vote.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage/67132#67132 ?

Comment: Be aware of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/vote-count-not-correct - So I don't know, if it has something to do with your problem.

Comment: Its 1 + for me from diff machine also.

Comment: @KennyTM - I know the link you posted would indicate that is the issue but the Questions and Answers are all in the last 20 mins?

Comment: Odd that this would happen on the same day as [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67448/my-rep-decreased-not-due-to-a-downvote); coincidence or weird bug?

Answer (score -2):

1. votes to community wiki posts do not add reputation
2. if you have hit the rep cap of 200/day then upvotes do not add reputation. (but accepted answer and bounties do)

see https://stackoverflow.com/faq and https://stackoverflow.com/privileges for more

Comment: it is not the case

Comment: @org probably just denormalized vote counts being off then (search meta for more information on this). Wait 36 hours and if the count is still off email us.

Comment: mail sent

Comment: Thanks Jeff,It happened for particular duration of time, I don't know how +1 vote decreased to 0 up vote.