# How can a post have an overall score of +1 with 0 up and 1 down votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

I've been notified of <strike>[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application/3929864#3929864)</strike> (meanwhile deleted) at score 0, upvoted it, realized it being a [duplicate of this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application/2932076#2932076) and removed my upvote again, yielding 0 as expected. Later on I added a respective comment and because apparently somebody else upvoted the post in the meantime I tried to downvote accordingly - my vote has been locked already though (I'm aware of the respective constraints, that's not the issue).

Strangely though, clicking *View upvote and downvote totals* now reveals a score of *0 up / -1 down*, yet tallying at +1 overall?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I see a downvote on my answer but nothing recorded in my recent activity?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67905/why-do-i-see-a-downvote-on-my-answer-but-nothing-recorded-in-my-recent-activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a race condition on the denormalized data. It seems to be correct now.

Comment: Confirmed - still a bit puzzling: your explanation seems to imply some upvote has incorrectly been shown for a quite a while and magically turned into a downvote just yet (because neither one has been from me)?

Comment: @Steffen - well, I deliberately voted and removed my vote, to nudge it...

Comment: @Marc - I figured you'd triggered it, but that's not what I mean: the system showed a score of +1 for quite a while, yet -1 in the details; you triggered the latter being correctly shown as score now as well, but this neither explains, where the one upvote originated in the first place, nor how it turned into a downvote at some point in time - of course, somebody else *might* have downvoted without a comment, though this seems rather unlikely given the answer at hand and chain of events? Anyway, will show up again if really an issue, so I'm going to accept your answer, thanks for following up!

Comment: @Steffen, this is likely a side effect of [the recent outage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage).

Comment: @Steffen Just as a note, this has happened actually a handful of times yesterday. Being a side-effect of the outage seems to be a likely case.

Comment: @Popular / @Grace - The meanwhile deleted answer has been a new one though, but depending on the database design the outage might still affect even ones of course; thanks for the hints!

Comment: @Steffen It also happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924006/create-and-integrate-jsf-components "But not visible, but it used to be 1 with a readout of 0/-1") and a similar report is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67465/upvote-is-not-being-counted "See the comments"). Neither is from the period of the outage, but my thought is that it's the only recent big change that I can think of which might be causing this brand of wonkiness.